Using Twn4 NFC Reader in a spring boot application
I have an employee time tracking application and I want to integrate this twn4 multiTech 2 to mark the presence by an nfc tag for employees, I developed my application with spring boot and MySQL for database (xampp phpMyAdmin), and I use Tomcat as a server.
So I tried to make it work with my app but it didn't work, I've downloaded the DevPack for the twn4 from their website elatec-rfid.com and I did install the driver , but still doesn't work.
I am a student in my last year and this is my graduation project, I'm really stuck in this and need help, So Every Information Would Be Appreciated, Thank You.
I've made a class that can take the value from the reader and store it in the database but I have no idea how it would work or what I am supposed to do. Somebody have told me that I should connect it to the tomcat server, but I have no idea how. Here is the code that I have tried:
package ma.fsts.nfcreaderapp.service;




import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;

import ma.fsts.nfcreaderapp.entities.Agent;
import ma.fsts.nfcreaderapp.entities.Pointage;
import ma.fsts.nfcreaderapp.entities.PointageSens;
import ma.fsts.nfcreaderapp.entities.Pointeuse;
import ma.fsts.nfcreaderapp.repositories.AgentRepository;
import ma.fsts.nfcreaderapp.repositories.PointageRepository;
import ma.fsts.nfcreaderapp.repositories.PointageSensRepository;
import ma.fsts.nfcreaderapp.repositories.PointeuseRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Service
public class NFCReaderService {

    @Autowired
    private PointageRepository pointageRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PointageSensRepository pointageSensRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PointeuseRepository pointeuseRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AgentRepository agentRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void readNFC() {
        SerialPort serialPort = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM7");
        serialPort.setBaudRate(9600);
        serialPort.setNumDataBits(8);
        serialPort.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_SEMI_BLOCKING, 1000, 0);
        serialPort.setNumStopBits(SerialPort.ONE_STOP_BIT);
        serialPort.setParity(SerialPort.NO_PARITY);

        if (serialPort.openPort()) {
            try (InputStream inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
                 OutputStream outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream()) {

                byte[] command = new byte[]{0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03};
                outputStream.write(command);

                byte[] response = new byte[128];
                int len = inputStream.read(response);
                String uid = new String(response, 0, len).trim();
                System.out.println("Read UID: " + uid);

                storeInDatabase(uid);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                serialPort.closePort();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to open the port.");
        }
    }

    private void storeInDatabase(String uid) {
        Pointage pointage = new Pointage();
        pointage.setRef(uid);
        pointage.setDatePointage(LocalDateTime.now());

        // Example: You should fetch these entities from the database or create them as needed
        PointageSens pointageSens = pointageSensRepository.findById(1L).orElse(null); // Example ID
        Pointeuse pointeuse = pointeuseRepository.findById(1L).orElse(null); // Example ID
        Agent agent = agentRepository.findById(1L).orElse(null); // Example ID

        pointage.setPointageSens(pointageSens);
        pointage.setPointeuse(pointeuse);
        pointage.setAgent(agent);

        pointageRepository.save(pointage);
    }
}


